# stuck at this command loop, trying to get right answer for this query commands

Tags: sql, database, select, command, exists

```
EMPLOYEE (fname, minit, lname, ssn, birthdate, address, sex, salary, superssn, dno)     KEY: ssn
DEPARTMENT (dname, dnumber, mgrssn, mgrstartdate)               KEY: dnumber.
PROJECT  (pname, pnumber, plocation, dnum)                          KEY: pnumber.
WORKS_ON (essn, pno, hours)                                         KEY: (essn, pno)
DEPENDENT  (essn, dependent-name, sex, bdate, relationship)             KEY: (essn, dependent-name)
```

Basically I want to get first, last names and the social security of each of the female managers with no dependents.

Here is what I wrote so far:

```
select e.fname, e.lname, e.ssn
from employee e, department d

where d.mgrssn = e.ssn
and e.sex = 'f'
and not exist in (

    select *
    ?
)
```

I'm basically stuck at the select statement inside my loop, what should be inside of it?

Comment: There is no loop. (See my answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use a NOT IN rather than EXISTS:

```
SELECT e.fname, e.lname, e.ssn
FROM employee e, department d
WHERE d.mgrssn = e.ssn
AND e.sex = 'f'
AND e.ssn not in (
    SELECT essn
    FROM dependant
)
```

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 0):

You want there to be no rows when you select the dependents of a female manager. So write a select that returns e.essn's dependents and nest it inside `NOT EXISTS (` `)`. Or, you want there to be no e.essn when you select the ssns of all dependents. So write a select that returns dependents' essns and nest it inside `e.ssn NOT IN`()`.

PS: There is no loop! A select statement's FROM clause creates a table with every possible combination of rows from both tables with column names *table*.*column*. (You can leave out the *table*. if *column* is unique.) Then it keeps only the rows that satisfy the WHERE. Then you must get rid of duplicate _column_s in the SELECT clause.